# Build failed in Openshift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, thymeleaf

I am trying to build a Spring Boot Thymeleaf applicatin in Openshift, but I am getting an error that does not show in my localhost web page.
See the an extract of the error below.

Any help is really appreciated.

```
[WARNING] The requested profile "openshift" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project SalaoWebs017: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project SalaoWebs017: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find main class
at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.buildManifest(Repackager.java:358)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:277)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:262)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:194)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.repackage(RepackageMojo.java:217)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.execute(RepackageMojo.java:204)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
... 21 more
```

Below also the pom.xml, not sure how the plugin part would be the cause of the error

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBootThymeleaf</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SpringBootThymeleaf</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <attach>false</attach>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: The error message is: "Unable to find main class". Please check if your application has a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation and a main method.

Comment: The main method is annotated with @SpringBootApplication and when I run in my machine I can see running ok with the web page at the port localhost:8080 with no problem. Wonder if there is additional setup in Openshift to not have this error

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml?